# Google Maps SDK returns iOS error in physical device but works fine in Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 3 and I'm trying to use Google Maps SDK for iOS. I compiled my code and ran it in the iOS simulator and it work perfectly. However, in my physical iPad and iPhone, the app won't work and show an error telling me:

> provideAPIKey: should be called at most once

---

I have enabled the APIs in Google's API console and also tried restricting the API key for iOS only but nothing works.

Note: I've included comments in my code to explaining the functions.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyDpyBvqZpZnRZIf-m1HNuh_vjdX3GUlmWM")
```

**// HERE IS THE ERROR**

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 15.0)

    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    ********************************************************************


    self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true

    self.mapView.camera = camera


    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
    // A minimum distance a device must move before update event generated
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 500
    // Request permission to use location service
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    // Request permission to use location service when the app is run
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    // Start the update of user's location
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()




    let latitudmia = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
    let longitudmia = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
```

**// Parsing Json and place markers with data**

**// I'm using swiftyJson to parse a JSON and get data with for loop**

```
     let urlStringdatos = "http://softkitect.tech/sandbox/maps/greetings3.php"



    let url=URL(string: urlStringdatos)!

    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
        (data,response,error) in


        guard let data = data else{
            print("data was nil?")
            return
        }


        let json = JSON(data: data)
        for index in 0...19 {


            let nombres = json[index]["title"].string
            let direccion = json[index]["descripcion"].string
            let latp = json[index]["latitud"].string
            let lngp = json[index]["longitud"].string




            if(nombres?.isEmpty == false && direccion?.isEmpty == false ){

                let latitudlug = Double(latp!)
                let lagitudlug = Double(lngp!)

                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {




                        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
                        let marker = GMSMarker()
                        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lagitudlug!, longitude: latitudlug!)
                        marker.title = nombres
                        print("MArcador latylong")
                        print(latitudlug!)
                         print(lagitudlug!)
                        marker.snippet = direccion
                        marker.map = self.mapView
                        print("MArcador Puestofinal")
                }

            }else{print("no hay lugares")}

        }



        // print(json["results"][0]["name"])
        //print(json["results"]["geometry"][0]["location"]["lat"].string)

    }
    session.resume()


}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {


    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    //Do What ever you want with it





    print(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    print(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow the instructions on how to use the Google Maps API here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start?hl=en-us

> Add your API key to your AppDelegate.swift as follows:
>
> Add the following import statement:
>
> ```
> import GoogleMaps
> ```
>
> Add the following to your `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`
>   method, replacing `YOUR_API_KEY` with your API key:
>
> ```
> GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
> ```
>
> If you are also using the
>   Places API, add your key again as shown here:
>
> ```
> GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY")
> ```

Please put your `provideAPIKey` method call in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in your app delegate.

Also, since the error says that `provideAPIKey` can only be called once, search your project for `provideAPIKey` and make sure there is only one call and that call is in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.